# Everything after/before regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have multiple instances of string with the next structure:

```
RT @username: Tweet text
```

I need to capture the username (to later construct a network). 
So far I have this:

```
re.findall('\@(.*)')
```

which should get everything after '@', but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get everything before (excluding) ':'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get everything between `@` and `:`, you can use the pattern:

```
@([^:]+)
```

Below is a breakdown of what it matches:

```
@      # @
(      # The start of a capture group
[^:]+  # One or more characters that are not :
)      # The close of the capture group
```

And here is a demonstration:

```
>>> from re import findall
>>> mystr = '''\
... RT @username: Tweet text
... RT @abcde: Tweet text
... RT @vwxyz: Tweet text
... '''
>>> findall('@([^:]+)', mystr)
['username', 'abcde', 'vwxyz']
>>>
```

Comment: after tons of so answers, your answer worked.